# How to log values in jasmine

Tags: jasmine, console.log

is there a similar method to console.log in jasmine?   If I want to log out the values of the $controller or service I am mocking is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can console in jasmine, from terminal or browser, in both cases you can see it( in describe it or anyplace)

Comment: Essentially this could only be seen with a test runner right?

Comment: no, you can use jasmine under html, or by terminal with node, now im working with java maven and jasmine

Comment: The regular console.log can be used, but the log can only be found in the browser console and not in the Terminal. [Angular, Jasmine, Spector.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just be using `console.log(whatever)`. They use it on their docs too. 
[jasmine docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L46v.png)